# Hoping to create Joomla plugin to allow for custom admin templates in K2

Tags: php, joomla

So Ive figured out how to hack k2 to allow for multiple backend templates based on an items category. Its actually pretty simple, but required a hack in the k2 core.

In administrator/components/com_k2/views/item/view.html.php at line 305, just following:

```
$this->assignRef('form', $form);
```

I added:

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
$componentPath = JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates';
$componentFolders = JFolder::folders($componentPath);
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT template FROM #__templates_menu WHERE client_id = 0 AND menuid = 0";
$db->setQuery($query);
$defaultemplate = $db->loadResult();

if (JFolder::exists(JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$defaultemplate.DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates'.DS.'admin'.DS.$item->catid)) { 
$this->_addPath('template', JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$defaultemplate.DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates'.DS.'admin'.DS.$item->catid); 
    }
```

This makes me able to duplicate the folder and contents of /administrator/components/com_k2/views/item/tmpl, move it to templates/MY_TEMPLATE/html/com_k2/admin and rename the new folder with the category id I want to override.

This works great and I can totally customize my backend K2 templates by category, making everything much easier for clients, and making K2 much more like a full CCK.

So what I want to do is create an installable plugin that basically inserts this code just before the admin template is rendered. Not sure how to go about this though... any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple:

1. Look into how to create Joomla plugin. Here is [Joomla create plug-in tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin)
2. Learn more about plug-in behavior, here is [plug-in documentation and events](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin)
3. Write code :-)

Also, Joomla has a Sample plug-in in `/plugins/user/example.php` (this is not plugin that you want, but a good starting point).
You should create **System** plug-in that is fired either on `onAfterDispatch` or `onAfterRender`, you might have to play with events to get it right...

Here is rough draft:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );
jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');

/**
 * K2 Template Overload Plug-in
 *
 * @package     Joomla
 * @subpackage  System
 */
class  plgSystemK2template extends JPlugin
{

    function plgSystemCache(& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }

    public function onAfterDispatch()
    {
        //  WHAT IS THE PURPOSE OF THESE 2 VARS??
        $componentPath = JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates';
        $componentFolders = JFolder::folders($componentPath);

        //
        $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT template FROM #__templates_menu WHERE client_id = 0 AND menuid = 0";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $defaultemplate = $db->loadResult();

        if (JFolder::exists(JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$defaultemplate.DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates'.DS.'admin'.DS.$item->catid)) { 
            $this->_addPath('template', JPATH_SITE.DS.'templates'.DS.$defaultemplate.DS.'html'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'templates'.DS.'admin'.DS.$item->catid); 
        }
    }
}
```